# XPages: Can an SSJS function be reused on a single XPage without putting it in a library?

Tags: xpages-ssjs

I have a ssjs function that is only called a couple of times in a self-contained XPages custom control.

Is there a way to keep this function in the XPage/CustomControl itself and call it directly without storing it in a separate javascript library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how server-side javascript can be made available everywhere in the XPage (or Custom Control) without the need to place it in a Script Library:

Right under `<xp:view>`:

```
<xp:this.resources>
    <xp:script clientSide="false">
        <xp:this.contents>
            <![CDATA[${javascript:
                var testA = "123";
                function testB(){
                    return "123";
                }
                return true;
            }]]>
        </xp:this.contents>
    </xp:script>
</xp:this.resources>
```

Notes:

- It is necessary that the code ends with something like `return true` otherwise the server generates an error parsing js code.
- The `<xp:view>` resources get loaded in the order they are listed in the XML source. If you have code that depends on other code, make sure to order them properly.
- My previous answer (below) has the complication that quotations and new lines must be escaped, and it doesn't help that the javascript engine shipped with Domino 9 is outdated (ES ver 3).

---

*Previous answer from 2017:*

Add a ComputedField (e.g. name it '`local_ssjs`') and let it generate the desired shared js code as a string value.

E.g.: `"function returnFour(){retrun (4)};"`

In your event, obtain the shared code and use the `eval()` function to *include* it.

`var sharedCode = getComponent("local_ssjs").getValue(); eval(sharedCode); var xFour = returnFour();`

Even if the computed field only contains function definitions, this works ok.

Comment: What do you know, 5 years later, I come back help to get help from my old self.

Answer (score 2):

I second what Georg says. Put the function in a library, but only include it as a resource on the custom control/xpage that will be doing the calls so it is not loaded on other pages/controls where not needed

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion it isn't possible, because you have no "global scope" and therefore you can't reference your function from different events in your xpage/custom control. You have to put this SSJS function in a library!